# Renameing categories didn't change URL Key and old names of categories still the same in product-catalog page

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, url-key

I renamed the categories name in admin panel.

It is successfully changed after fixing a bug related to URL rewrites, then I faced another problem that URL Keys of each category map to the old category name.

Also when I open Products catalog page **(/product-catalog.html)** in front-end the old name of categories didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by editing the custom block under content.
I updated the html view and it is rendered on the front-end correctly